# What does it mean "ip based protocol"?

Tags: ip, protocols

I read in Wikipedia, an expression "IP-based protocol".
Do we have any "non-IP-based protocol"?
What are other protocols which are not "IP-based protocol"?(what is the similar categories?)

> Access to a certain IP address is denied. If the target Web site is hosted on a shared hosting server, all websites on the same server will be blocked. This affects IP-based protocols such as HTTP, FTP, and POP.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship#Content_suppression_methods

Answer (score 0):

The actual meaning of IP-based protocol is that if some protocol(Like TCP, HTTP, POP, FTP, TLS/SSL) uses IP protocol in the internet layer of TCP/IP model for the transportation of their actual data.

HTTP is a application layer protocol which uses IP in internet layer.

There can be non-IP-based protocol if they do not uses IP protocol at all. For example all protocols of data link layer are can be said non IP based or we can say they  do not uses the services of IP. Eg. ARP, NDP, OSPF